# Meteor not detecting new files

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Whenever I create new directories or files inside 'imports/ui/' the changes are not detected.

The error goes away and everything works fine as soon as I manually restart the server.

Is this behavior intentional? Can I change it so Meteor detects new files automatically?

This is my code:

```
//client/main.js
import '../imports/ui/body.js';
```

_

```
//imports/ui/body.js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './body.html';

Template.body.helpers({
  tasks: [
  { text: 'This is task 1' },
  { text: 'This is task 2' },
  { text: 'This is task 3' },
  ],
});
```

_

```
//imports/ui/body.html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
      {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

This is the error I get on Chrome's console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './template.body.js'
>       at require (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=ab7e8d32b6c7b5a5fa7ae1b65e8225c4f9e30223:119:19)
>       at meteorInstall.imports.ui.body.html (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=daa6958260cc1e0c5e80d55b2d8741e114835c8d:9:18)
>       at fileEvaluate (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=ab7e8d32b6c7b5a5fa7ae1b65e8225c4f9e30223:191:9)
>       at Module.require (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=ab7e8d32b6c7b5a5fa7ae1b65e8225c4f9e30223:116:16)
>       at Module.Mp.import (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=d99e0932efe1a420b80cdbd95cd57dc3604a8456:314:16)
>       at meteorInstall.imports.ui.body.js (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=daa6958260cc1e0c5e80d55b2d8741e114835c8d:21:99)
>       at fileEvaluate (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=ab7e8d32b6c7b5a5fa7ae1b65e8225c4f9e30223:191:9)
>       at Module.require (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=ab7e8d32b6c7b5a5fa7ae1b65e8225c4f9e30223:116:16)
>       at Module.Mp.import (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=d99e0932efe1a420b80cdbd95cd57dc3604a8456:314:16)
>       at meteorInstall.client.main.js (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=daa6958260cc1e0c5e80d55b2d8741e114835c8d:38:14)

Comment: It seems like it is detecting changes although you have an error in your code, therefore it is not loading the page. I can't help you unless you post the full error and code.

Comment: @TristanWiley It is only detecting changes on files that already exist when the server is launched.

Comment: Meteor detects any file changes, even in imports/ui and will trigger a rebuild. as @TristanWiley suggests, something else must be wrong. A meteor reset might help, as might rebooting your machine

Comment: Or it could just be a code error. Post your code and full error if you want more help.

Comment: @TristanWiley I'm just copying the code from the official tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

Comment: Is it directly in the C9 app folder? Not any subfolder?

Comment: @TristanWiley Yes. And I was able to reproduce this on another server

Answer (score 0):

Set the project's Meteor version to a previous one:

```
meteor update --release 1.4.1.3
```

(Thanks to [diaconutheodor](https://forums.meteor.com/users/diaconutheodor/activity))

[Source](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-not-detecting-new-files/31151/8?u=fbsn)